# Quick Action - Detail Button Page Error - LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, quickaction, lwc-dom

can anyone help me with this error,
My requirement is:
I have a Detail page button called Convert on Order Object, when I click on the convert button it should convert the order object Record to Invoice, which is working fine but the Navigation and Toast Messages are not working (I am using Detail Page Button). Like when the record is converted it should navigate to the Invoice record page and when I click on cancel, It should navigate to Order Record Page, both scenarios are not working

I'm grateful and appreciate your help in advance..!

if (this.value) {
this.boolShowSpinner = true;
convertButtonLWC({
OId: this.recordId
})

```
            .then((result) => {
               this.boolShowSpinner = false;
               //this.orderData = result
               console.log('Invoice Creation' + JSON.stringify(result))
               if(result == null){this.invoiceCreatedError = true;}
               if (result) {
                  this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                     type: 'standard__recordPage',
                     attributes: {
                        recordId: result,
                        actionName: 'view',
                     },
                  });
               }
            })
      }
```

[image: Facing Error in VS Code]Facing Error in VS Code

[image: Detail Page Button on Order Object]Detail Page Button on Order Object

[image: Code for navigating to Invoice record page]Code for navigating to Invoice record page

[image: Code for cancel button]Code for cancel button

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code as code (use the `{}` button for formatting the code correctly). In addition, your screenshot shows a Visualforce page here; NavigationMixin won't work in this scenario, as it can only work in the Lightning Experience or Digital Experience directly. Have you tried creating a Quick Action?

Comment: Yes, I have tried and but I am getting an error as "Lightning Web Component quick actions are not supported for this entity" @sfdcfox